# AngularJS: Change checkbox list to bold on check?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

```
<div class='someClass'>
     <label ng-repeat="item in itemList">
           <input type='checkbox' checklist-model='itemCheckList' checklist-value='item.name'>
           <span class='label-text' ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Trying to figure out how to change the text to bold when the checkbox is checked and not bold when unchecked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Angular (not JS) has the ngClass directive (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). Maybe AngularJS has something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached this to my styling and it worked.

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.label-text{
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does item have a property like isChecked or similar boolean value?  ie. item.isChecked. If so, you can use the angularjs ng-class.

```
// html 
 <span class='label-text' ng-class="{ 'selected': item.isChecked }" ng-bind-html="item.name"></span>

// css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```